# Clear UserControl with Dependency Property in Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a number of **UserControl** (a Grid with few Labels) being generated and added to **Canvas** in runtime. I have implemented drag-and-drop for each UserControl and node line (or connector line) between UserControls.

When I clear the UserControl with **myCanvas.Children.Clear()**, I received the following error in method **Node_LayoutUpdated()**:

[image]

This is my UserControl:

```
public partial class Foo : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnchorPointProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AnchorPoint", typeof(Point), typeof(Foo),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(0, 0),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    public Point AnchorPoint
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(AnchorPointProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnchorPointProperty, value); }
    }

    private Canvas mCanvas;

    public Foo(Canvas canvas, bool isInput)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mCanvas = canvas;
        this.LayoutUpdated += Node_LayoutUpdated;
    }

    void Node_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Size size = RenderSize;
        Point ofs = new Point(size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2);
        AnchorPoint = TransformToVisual(this.mCanvas).Transform(ofs);
    }
}
```

Am I supposed to remove the DependencyProperty before removing the UserControl, and how? Can someone please explain what causes this error message and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is the last line of your code. The `LayoutUpdated` event is invoked right after you remove (Clear) the children of the Canvas. `TransformToVisual` doesn't work if the Control is already detached from the VisualTree. Subscribing to parent layout events is usually neither required nor a good idea. A quick workaround would be to *detach* the control before the `Clear`.

Add this code to your UserControl:

```
public void Detach()
{    
    this.LayoutUpdated -= Node_LayoutUpdated;
}
```

And this to your MainWindow:

```
foreach(WhateverYourControlTypeIs control in myCanvas.Children)
{
    control.Detach();
}
myCanvas.Children.Clear();
```

Comment: Because the function Node_LayoutUpdated reside in the UserControl, I cannot detach it in MainWindows, and I get "The Name Node_LayoutUpdated does not exist in the current context". How do I detach it then?

Comment: @KMC Well, the easiest way would be to put the code in a public method of your UserControl (e.g. implement the `IDisposable` interface to your UserControl, put the detach code in there) and call it manually before removing it. You could also catch the exception and detach the event when an `InvalidOperationException` occurs. Instead of setting `mCanvas` in your constructor, you could [use the VisualTreeHelper to find the control's parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type) on demand.

Comment: sorry but I do not follow you. What is the point of making Node_LayoutUpdated public? That would still not be accessible in MainWindows - what what do you mean by calling it manually?

Comment: Add a public method to your UserControl. Name that method `Detach`. In that method, add `this.LayoutUpdated -= Node_LayoutUpdated;`. Before you call `myCanvas.Children.Clear()` in your MainWindow, iterate through all UserControls in `myCanvas.Children`. Call `Detach` on each of them.